# Relation between bandwidth and play time in a CD

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

I have recently read that uncompressed CD-quality audio has a bandwidth of 1.411 Mbps in case of stereo, does it mean a CD can be played to output audio at the rate of 1.411 Mbps, i mean does it play 1.411 Mbits of stereo audio every second..?

Comment: Yes. It's uncompressed and has a fixed bit-rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two channels, each with 44,100 16-bit samples per second. That is 2 x 44100 x 16 = 1,411,200bps. That is 1.411Mbps.  (176400 bytes per second)

Each second requires 1.411Mb. If you reduced the sample rate by half, you would double the number of seconds that can be recorded on a CD. Same if you dropped it to one channel, or 8-bit.

To imagine the impact of reducing the sample rate, lets suppose a technology that sampled every 1 second. This would be like pressing mute over and over, you would only catch parts.

Reducing the channel to one is easy to imagine, that's monaural.

Reducing to 8-bit is harder to describe. Imagine we reduced it to 1-bit. That would essentially mean the speaker has two states, fully centered and fully driven. That is not much variation. 16 bits gives 65536 positions.

Comment: 2 channels x 44,100 Hz x 16 bits = 1,411,200 bits per second

Comment: Typo in calculator, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @sbooth I am kind of looking for the relation between play time of CD and its bandwidth. Can you guys please explain that.

Comment: @chet what does this 1.411Mbps mean...so it can record 1.411Mb in a second and can be played at the same rate..?

Comment: Yes.  Precisely that.

Comment: I have modified my answer to give the signfiicance of the bitrate.